# strtok() not printing correct value

Tags: c, strtok

I'm reading a CSV file with C and want to store the the tokens from strtok() in an array. Somehow, when the CSV file has multiple lines, I don't get the correct output of the tokens. The CSV file looks like this (Just two lines for this example, the real file will have more than 100 lines):

```
abc,def,ghi

jkl,mno
```

My code is:

```
    void main() {



    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("simple.csv", "r");
    const char s[2] = ",";
    char *token;
    char *out[5];
    int i = 0;
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        char line[50];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
        {
            token = strtok(line, s);

            //for (token; token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, ","))
            while (token != NULL)
            {
                out[i++] = token;
                //printf("%s", token);
                token = strtok(NULL, s);

            }

            printf("%s\n", out[0]);

        }

        //for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)


        fclose(fp);
    }
    else {
        printf("error opening file");
    }
}
```

I want each comma delimited string to be stored in an array through a loop.
When i print out the 1st element of the array (`out[0]`) , the output is:

```
abc

jkl
```

while i expect it to be just the token:

abc

Can anyone please let me know what the problem is?

Comment: You are using the *same* `line` buffer for *every* `fgets`. So of course the results are overwritten every line of input.

Comment: I'm a newbie. can you please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: yes they are the first columns. I would like to store each of the strings in the CSV file into an array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `strtok` returns pointers pointing to several places of `line`, whose contents changes all the time.

Thus, you need to copy the token's content, not just assign pointers.

For example, define `out` to be:

```
char out[5][10];  // max of 5 words, each of 10 chars max (including \0)
```

and inside the loop:

```
strcpy(&out[i++][0], token);
```